# Capture number of lines of output and return code simultaneously

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that will call a program (lets call it foo) that returns some output, and gives a return code. I care about both the return code of program and the number of lines output (but not the output itself). Because the program involves retrieving data over the internet, I would prefer not to have to invoke it twice (in particular, this could cause problems if only one of the two invokations fail due to a transient network issue or something similar). The best script I can come up with to capture both the number of output lines and return code is the following. Is there something more elegant?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
line=$(foo | wc -l; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
line=$(echo line | tr '\n' ' ')
lineCount=$(echo line | awk '{ print $1}')
returnCode=$(echo line | awk '{ print $2}')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
set -o pipefail
lineCount=$(foo | wc -l)
returnCode=$?
```

This assumes that `wc` never fails, otherwise you get `wc`'s exit status.

Another way that doesn't depend on this assumption:

```
set +o pipefail
lineCount=$(foo | wc -l ; exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}")
returnCode=$?
```

Comment: I like that second method very much. The set +o pipefail could be omitted assuming pipefail is not set earlier in the script, right?

Comment: @spectre256: Yes, I've added it only for emphasis that `pipefail` is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Eleganter, but still awkward:

```
{ read lineCount; read returnCode; } < <(foo | wc -l; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
```

If you don't expect the output to be huge, I'd just capture it and then work with it:

```
output=$(foo)
returnCode=$?
lineCount=$(wc -l <<< "$output")
```

Answer (score 1):

1 liner `(exit $(foo | wc -l))`

For example;

```
$ (exit $(echo "line1\nline2" | wc -l))
$ echo $?
2
```

Comment: in c in system(), needs in .sh $() is not ok ; and short return >>8 for working