# Check PDF if document is blank in bash or ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, pdf

I'm trying merge several pdf files into one page. I am using ghostcript to merge all of them but I have problem when I merge one with a blank page.  So I have to check each one for a blank pdf document. Is there any way to do this with the standard bash shell or Ruby language?

I am using pdffonts to identify if the pdf is blank or not. I'm using the command :

> pdffonts 00001.pdf

and if the pdf is blank the result is :

```
name                                type              emb sub uni object ID

------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
```

if the pdf is not blank the result is

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
Helvetica                            Type 1            no  no  no       6  0
```

Comment: So, if I know which document is blank I can remove them from list.. :D

Comment: Hi Adhown, what is the error you receive when you try to merge them together using ghost script?

Comment: Hi Sunny, there is no error but I mean, I want to merge all pdf without blank page. Because I have so many pdf files but there is include blank page too. :(

Comment: Are all the PDFs with blank pages the same size? I mean their kilobytes.

Comment: Sunny, No, the size is different because the pdf is come from scanning.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done simply then adhown. The most clever thing I can think of is turning it into an image and and getting all the colors that appear on the page to see if it ever isn't white.

Comment: ok sunny, thanks for your suggestion. I am trying to use `pdffonts` to check if pdf is blank. :D .

Comment: Good idea! If you manage to find a solution, be sure to post it and mark your question answered.

Comment: Hi Sunnny, I already use pdffonts but I confuse when I want to grep pdf blank.. I edit my question above perhaps you can give me some suggestion.. :d

Comment: Try something like this, which displays how many fonts each .pdf in your current directory contains: for fic in $( ls *.pdf ); do (echo -n "$fic : " ; pdffonts $fic | grep -E -v '^name|^------' | wc -l);  done

Comment: This version shows your blank pdf files : for fic in $( ls *.pdf ); do ( nb_fonts=$(pdffonts $fic | grep -E -v '^name|^------' |  wc -l) ;  if [ ${nb_fonts} -eq 0 ] ; then echo "$fic is empty"; fi);  done

Comment: You may also use pdftotext (I haven't tested on files containing only images, though)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about bash programming but it seems feasible to write a program that will call pdffonts on every file in your directory, count the number of lines returned, if that number is greater than 2 than add that to the merge else move into a directory called blank_pdfs.

Here is how you can count the number of lines returned by a program in bash.

[Capture number of lines of output and return code simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623801/capture-number-of-lines-of-output-and-return-code-simultaneously)

Comment: hhmm.. Thanks sunny.. but I still confused. :(

Comment: What part is confusing to you?

Answer (score 1):

`gs -sDEVICE=bbox` will give you the minimal bounding box for a file/page. It should be *very* small for empty pages.

Comment: This answer is PERFECT. The full ghostscript command I used was: `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -sDEVICE=bbox <inputFile.pdf>` If all the BoundingBox lines are `0 0 0 0` then you have an empty PDF.